# mailjet plugin - extend functionnalities and reuse api

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

At the beginning, i was using the classic apache sendmail to send email  from my custom forms. Finaly i decide to use Mailjet o send all: forms submission and transactional email. I install the plugin and it works well.

As Mailjet API is install throught the plugin, i would like to rely on the plugin to send newsletter subscriptions and unsubscriptions, to send automation trigger.

I check the doc:
https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#contactslist_managemanycontacts
And notice than i can use:

`$apikey = get_option('mailjet_password');`

`$apisecret =  get_option('mailjet_username');`

I try tu use ajax and a function similar to the API documentation but it doesn't seems to work:

```
function sendRegisterNewsletter($list_id, $email, $firstname, $name, $job, $structure) {

$apikey = get_option('mailjet_password');
$apisecret =  get_option('mailjet_username');

require '../../plugins/mailjet-for-wordpress/api/mailjet-api-v3.php';
use \Mailjet\Resources;
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client($apikey, $apisecret);

}
```

I get a error with "use": syntax error, unexpected T_USE use

As i use the plugin, i don't think it was useful to use the module:
https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php

Any advice to use the configured plugin and Mailjet's api?
Thank you in advance for any help.

jb

Answer (score 0):

Because the template is load before the plugin, i finaly decide to add the API directly from https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-no-composer

I check the api:
https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?php#contactslist_managemanycontacts

And build my function to send a contact to a list:

```
// Get the value from the plugin mailjet-for-wordpress
$apisecret = get_option('mailjet_password');
$apikey = get_option('mailjet_username');

require 'mailjet-apiv3-php-no-composer/vendor/autoload.php';

use \Mailjet\Resources;

function sendRegisterNewsletterToMailjet($params) {

$mj = new \Mailjet\Client($apikey, $apisecret);

$body = [
'Action' => "addforce",
'Contacts' => [
[
'Email' => $params['Email'],
'Properties' => [
'prénom' => $params['prénom'],
'nom' => $params['nom'],
'profession' => $params['profession'],
'structure' => $params['structure'],
]
],
]
];

$response = $mj->post(Resources::$ContactslistManagemanycontacts, ['id' => $params['ListID'], 'body' => $body]);
$response->success() && var_dump($response->getData());

wp_send_json_success($response);

}
```

The problem is i get this response:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":
        {
            "request":{
            "type":"application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    "Count": 1,
    "Data": [
        {
            "JobID": 35800
        }
    ],
    "Total": 1
}
```

Any idea?